# Getting rid of files from domain name using PHP

Tags: php, replace

I have the following URLs:

```
http://website.com/folder1/file.php
http://website.com/folder2/file.html
```

I want to know if there is any way in PHP that will let me hide the files and their extensions so the URLs will look like this:

```
http://website.com/folder1/
http://website.com/folder2/
```

I know this is possible using htaccess and mod_rewrite but I want to do it using PHP only.

Comment: "...That will let me delete the files and their extensions..." You don't really mean that you want to delete the files, right? You just want to change the displayed URL?

Comment: hahahahahahahahahaha yes bro sorry xD

Comment: I meant just delete them from appearing xD

Answer (score 1):

ok I found the answer :

```
<? echo dirname("http://website.com/folder1/file.php"); ?>
```

so the url will look like this :

```
http://website.com/folder1/
```

Comment: That just prints out the URL, though. It doesn't make the web server accept requests to it.

Answer (score 0):

`dirname` removes the last part of the URL.

To remove a specific string at the end of the URL if it exists, use `rtrim`:

```
$url = rtrim($url, 'file.php');
// http://website.com/folder/
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
// http://website.com/folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a way via file extension detection:

```
function removeFilenameFromURL($url)
{
    $urlPath = pathinfo($url);

    // Remove if the URL has an file extension
    if (isset($urlPath['extension'])) {
        $lastPos = strripos($url, "/");
        $url = substr($url, 0, $lastPos + 1);
    }

    return $url;
}

echo dirname("https://localhost/subdir/index.php") . "<br>";
echo removeFilenameFromURL("https://localhost/subdir/index.php") . "<br>";
echo phpversion();

OUTPUT:
https://localhost/subdir
https://localhost/subdir/
7.4.23
```

This always ensures a trailing slash.

**ATTENTION:**
With dirname() function on PHP 7.4 the trailing slash is gone ... (changing behavior on different PHP versions??)