# php remove filename from url if exists

Tags: php, preg-replace, pathinfo

hello I would like to remove all filenames from my url :

```
http://website.com/folder1/folder2/filename.php
```

here is what I have tried :

```
$file_info = pathinfo('http://website.com/folder1/folder2/filename.php');
echo $file_info['dirname'];
```

outputs http://website.com/folder1/folder2/ wich is what I want , but when I try this :

```
   $file_info = pathinfo('http://website.com/folder1/folder2/');
    echo $file_info['dirname'];
```

it outputs http://website.com/folder1/.   
now what I want is if the url contains a filename then it gets removed , and if url has only folders then do nothing .
(I don't want to use .htaccess for this)

Comment: I don't see a point in this. Where does the url come from? Is it a link you want to send out? In other words what do you mean by "my url" here?

Comment: my website receives many referers urls so I want to remove filenames from them

Comment: if some doesn't have filenames then it's ok I won't do nothing to them but if some have filenames at the end I want to remove them

Comment: that's all what I want

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you are asking. Are you talking about incoming requests? Why would you want to alter such a url inside the requested script then? That makes no sense.

Comment: I think everything is clear

Comment: You could just append something to the string before passing it to path info: `$file_info = pathinfo($path . 'suffix');` That would make `dirname` work properly.

Comment: I think I  have to use substr but substr start from left to right my question is is there a function like substr that starts from right to left so I will use strpos with it

Comment: Yes you can use substr and pass negative argument like `substr($str, -1)` will return last character from `$str` and `substr($str,-5)` will return last 5 characters from `$str`

Comment: ok thanks @meLove I will go try  I hope I find solution

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31493950

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all filenames have an extension:

```
$url1 = 'http://website.com/folder1/folder2/filename.php';
$url2 = 'http://website.com/folder1/folder2/';

echo removeFilename($url1) . "\n";
echo removeFilename($url2) . "\n";

function removeFilename($url)
{
    $file_info = pathinfo($url);
    return isset($file_info['extension'])
        ? str_replace($file_info['filename'] . "." . $file_info['extension'], "", $url)
        : $url;
}
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for , thank you so much .

Answer (score 3):

You can try with [dirname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php)

```
echo dirname('http://website.com/folder1/folder2/filename.php');
```

Comment: no dirname will remove filename only if exists but if filename doesn't exist on url it will remove subdirectories too

Answer (score 0):

its impossible because you cant check if stackoverflow.de/post.new/tero.php is an filename or just an folder ...

in this case use checkup to check if the given path is a url or not